# Java 10 Bug in Midi Device Names

Tags: java, midi

Anyone doing Java Sound MIDI programming with Java 10? I'm finding that MIDI device names queried of the MidiSystem class have randomly-generated characters at the end of them. Would like to know if anyone else is having this problem.

Here's a simple test program to see the names of your MIDI devices on your system. Asking that if you try this, you build/run in on Java 8, Java 9, and Java 10. I get expected output for 8 and 9, and garbage characters for 10:

```
public class MidiDeviceNameBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo())
                .map(MidiDevice.Info::getName)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace `Arrays.asList(...).stream()` with `Arrays.stream(...)` or `Stream.of(...)`.

Comment: Which operating system is this?

Comment: What garbage? Show the actual output.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct about Arrays.stream(), I'll use that from now on!

Comment: I'm running on Windows 10.

Comment: Here is output on Windows 10 using Java 8: "Gervill"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboard"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In B"
"Microsoft MIDI Mapper"
"Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboard"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out B"
"Real Time Sequencer"

Comment: Here is output on Windows 10 using Java 9 (it's the same as the output above using Java 8): "Gervill"
"Real Time Sequencer"
"Microsoft MIDI Mapper"
"Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboard"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out B"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboard"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In B"

Comment: Here is output on Windows 10 using Java 10. Note that SOME of the MIDI device names are OK, others have weird "extended" characters at the end. These weird "extended characters" are different each time I run the code: "Real Time Sequencer"
"Unknown name"
"Microsoft GS Wavetable掄"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboû"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out B"
"LoopBe Internal MIû"
"MK-449C USB MIDI K"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In Aɳ"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In Bɳ"

Comment: Here's another run of output on Windows 10 using Java 10. Note that the weird characters at the end are different: "Gervill"
"Real Time Sequencer"
"Unknown name"
"Microsoft GS Wavetable⩐"
"LoopBe Internal MIDI"
"MK-449C USB MIDI Keyboû"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out A"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 Out B"
"LoopBe Internal MIû"
"MK-449C USB MIDI K"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In AȔ"
"MIDISPORT 2x2 In BȔ"

Comment: I could paste in more output for Java 10, but trust me, the weird characters are different each time I run the code I posted above.

Comment: Actually, I modified the code above to use Stream.of() (thanks!), and also to output the device names in quotes, to be sure to see where each  device name ends.

Comment: Modify the question instead of using the comments section as chat

Comment: How are we supposed to communicate if not via comments? I don't understand this thing.

Comment: There is a bug in JDK 10, it will be investigated.

Comment: I hope it can be fixed. I continue to write MIDI applications using Java Sound and JavaFX. I am extremely saddened the more I learn that both of these great technologies seem to be being systematically ignored and abandoned.